# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

[image: LAZERS AND LOUD NOISES]
Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: People were asking about elections last year, and [the general answer we were given was that elections only occur when more mods are needed or the current mods feel they need more help](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7945/3062) due to others leaving. Is there a particular reason we went from needing 0 more last year to needing 3 more this year? Traffic? Mods leaving?

Comment: @Sterno Simply, we as a mod team asked for an election with 3 spots and SE obliged.

Comment: @badp That doesn't really answer the question.  Is there a reason the mod team felt the need for 3 spots this year and none last year?  In hindsight would 1-2 extra mods have been helpful over the past year?

Comment: @MatthewRead No; until a few months ago we managed to balance the load reasonably well. That has changed recently. Since we are one of the most trafficked sites in the network, it makes sense to have a wide roster of moderators on duty. (I think that if we asked for 7 slots, SE would not have granted such a request.)

Comment: @badp Perfect, thanks for the insight.

Comment: So these are 3 *additional* mods.  Not 3 replacements?